# PHP - Form without action keeps GET data. Form with action (same url) don't

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

Kind of confused.Let me explain an example situation.

I have a form at delete.php (plain PHP, no framework) that receives a parameter through http get

When I send the form I've always thought that GET values are going to be lost therefore, If I want to keep those values I must use input type="hidden" , sessions or any other mechanism.

But using PHP 7.0.8, Apache 2.4(for sure it's not a version issue just wanted to let you know) I've realized the following:

a) If the action of the form is set to delete.php (the same url) GET values are lost once the form is submitted. As expected

b) If the action of the form is NOT set then data are sent to delete.php (as expected) but GET values are kept.

I don't know why and I can't find an explanation in any docs or http espec.

Does anybody know where is this situation explained?

Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GET / POST TEST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" ">
  </head>
  <body>

      <form method="post" action="get_post_test.php">
        Name<input type="text" name="name" required><br>
        LastName<input type="text" name="lastname" required><br>
        <p>
          <input type="submit">
        </p>
      </form>

      <?php

          if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
            echo "TENGO GET";
            var_dump($_GET);
          }

          if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
            echo "TENGO POST";
            var_dump($_POST);
          }
      ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting $_GET['id'] through a link and if:

a) action="get_post_test.php" then $_GET['id'] is lost when form submitting (as I expected because get_post_test.php is the name of the current file)

b) If I don't set any action $_GET['id'] still is available when submitting ????????

Kind regards.

Comment: I would recommend to show the code.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take an example

> **Case 1: When action is defined**
>
> When an action is defined then the form is submitted to that page.
>
> Ex: If your action is `delete.php` and the URL is `delete.php` then
>   form will send data as expected and the URL will become like this
>   `delete.php?KEY=VALYE&...` but the action of the form will be same
>   `delete.php` because you have defined it. Thats why previous data will be lost on resubmit
>
> **Case 2: When action is left blank.**
>
> When an action is left blank that means the action will be the same as
>   the url.
>
> Ex: When your URL is `delete.php` then the action will be the same as URL
>   `delete.php` thats why form will send data as expected. After that the URL
>   will become like this `delete.php?KEY=VALYE&...`. When you resubmit
>   the form then the action will be the same as url which already has the same
>   get values.

Hope this will help you to understand

Comment: I do understand that's why I'm suprised. Please see the code and further explanations recently posted.